# How to produce a soft return using C#.net

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, text

I know this is kind of easy question but i cant seem to find it anywhere. Is there someone out there who knows how to **create a soft return inside a set of text** using C#.net?

I need to print soft return to a text file/xml file. this text file will be generated using c#.net. you could verify if the answer is correct if you use NOTEPAD++ then enable the option to  “View>Show Symbol > Show End of Line” then you will see a symbol like this:

[image]

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please clarify your question. Do you just need to insert a newline at some place? Then Environment.NewLine is the way to go

Comment: IIRC, the old DOS "soft return" was ASCII character 141 (where a `CR` was ASCII 13 and `LF` was ASCII 10 (`0x0D` and `0x0A` respectively). I'm not positive my memory is right, though; it's been ages since I had to deal with that stuff, which is why I'm not posting it as an answer. I'm alsn not sure that's what you're really looking for; I think what you're looking for is an embedded return (CR/LF) in the csv file.

Comment: @KenWhite this is what im looking at right now :) nice idea from you ;) i just have to try it can you please post you're answer?

Comment: @Allan, I'm not sure how to do it in C#; I do C# work on occasion, but I primarily use Delphi (in Delphi, it's really easy - you just append `#141` to the string; not sure how to do the same in C#). Perhaps someone else can demonstrate that in an answer. :-)

Comment: if you want to follow Ken White's answers you could just append `(char)141`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by a soft return. A quick Google search says it's a non-stored line break typically due to word wrapping in which case you wouldn't actually put this in a string, it would only be relevant when the string was rendered for display.

To put a carriage return and/or line feed in the string you would use:

```
string s = "line one\r\nline two";
```

And for further reference, here are the other escape codes that you can use.

[Link (MSDN Blogs)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/what-character-escape-sequences-are-available.aspx)

**In response to your edit**

The LF that you see can be represented with `\n` in a string. Obviously you have a specific line ending sequence that you need to represent. If you were to use `Environment.NewLine` that is going to give you different results on different platforms.

Comment: nonono, not in C#. Your should use Environment.NewLine. Also in windows it's \n\r, in linux its \n, on mac it was iirc \r\n, but now is also \n

Comment: Actually yes that works in C# and on Windows the standard sequence is `\r\n` not `\n\r` as you state. Yes, there are platform-specific line endings, but unless he's using Mono or Silverlight, it's unlikely to come up.

Comment: It is \r\n on Windows, and Environment.NewLine is there for a reason.  Suggest it be used.

Comment: Crap, you are right. My mistake, it _is_ \r\n in Windows. But I still think we miss the OP's intention

Comment: Somebody downvoted me too for no apparent reason. You should be required to add a comment if you are going to downvote something.

Answer (score 3):

```
var message = $"Tom{Convert.ToChar(10)}Harry";
```

Results in:

Tom

Harry

With just a line feed between.

Comment: string s = $"Tom{(char)10}Harry";  //Same answer, just character conversion shorter syntax. There are 4 "characters", probably technically tokens, in ascii that feed text to the next line: 10 Line Feed, 11 Vertical Tab, 12 Form Feed, 13 Carriage Return. 0 - 31 are the special tokens. https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.html

Answer (score 0):

Lke already mentioned you can use Enviroment.NewLine but I am not sure if that i what you want or if you are actually trying to append a ASCII 141 to your string as mentioned in the comments.

You can add ASCII chr sequences to your string like this.

```
var myString = new StringBuilder("Foo");
myString.Append((char)141);
```

Comment: So no reasoning for the downvote? If you downvote at least leave a comment why